# How does sys.dm_exec_sql_text work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can you please explain why

`select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle)`
throws an error (Invalid column name 'sql_handle'), but

`select * from sys.sysprocesses cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (sql_handle)` is a valid query?
Thank you.

Comment: Because `sql_handle` is the name of a column in [`sys.sysprocesses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx)?

Comment: Thank you, Damien. But what is the meaning of this column? How can I test this function (dm_exec_sql_text) on its own or do we always need to use it in conjunction with another table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to join it to another table to get the sql_handle (or plan_handle).

For example:

```
select a.session_id, a.start_time, status, a.command, text from sys.dm_exec_requests a cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle).
```

`sys.dm_exec_sql_text` is a table valued function, it expects the parameter `sql_handle` or `plan_handle` to be passed to it in order to return a result as other functions do.  The result returned is a table (rather than a scalar function which would return a single value).

Comment: Thank you Simon! For a better understanding, I would like to ask:

`select distinct sql_handle from sys.sysprocesses` --this gives a number of sql_handles, representing "the currently executing batches or objects". However, if I do this:
`select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(convert(binary,'0x010001000B84CH15904B33000600000000000000'))`, it throws "The handle that was passed to dm_exec_sql_text was invalid." Why? (I am trying to use sys.dm_exec_sql_text on its own to understand it better)

Comment: @Anne - This is most likely a type conversion issue.  `select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(convert(binary,'0x010001000B84CH15904B33000600000000000000'‌​, 1))`.  The default style is 0 (ascii conversion).  For a character expression, add the ',1'.  See [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Just as a side note `sys.sysprocesses` is a deprecated 2000 system table which is only there for backwards compatibilty and will be removed in a future release.  From 2005 onwards have a look at `sys.dm_exec_connections`, `sys.dm_exec_sessions` and `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMVs.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179881.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon! Unfortunately, I still get an error even with `select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(convert(binary,'0x010001000B84CH15904B33000600000000000000'‌​‌​, 1))` : 
"The handle that was passed to dm_exec_sql_text was invalid." Any thoughts on this, please?

Comment: @Anne - Does this work?  I don't think the binary is valid, it has an H in it.  I didn't need to do any conversion at all... `select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(0x030005002D57016E1D8E1D00C8A1000001000000)`.  I had to use the ,1 if I wrapped it in the convert as you have done.

Comment: Yes, Simon, many thanks, it does work! I also can do something like `select * from sys.sysprocesses where sql_handle = convert(binary,'0x010006000ABA030300EBB17F0800000000000000',1)` (in a where clause), I just can't use the convert....as an argument to the sys.dm_exec_sql_text call, so thank you for the work-around. Have a nice day!