# Retrieve SQL text of ODBC prepared statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I use ODBC API to create a prepared statement:

```
SQLPrepare(hstmt, "INSERT INTO t (date) VALUES (?)", SQL_NTS);
```

Once the `SQLPrepare` completes with success, the statement is accessible via the `hstmt` handle.

Having the `hstmt` handle only, is there any way, an ODBC API call or other means, to retrieve the SQL text associated with the prepared statement?

In other words, is there any way to find out what SQL was passed to `SQLPrepare` call?

I only found [SQLNativeSql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714575.aspx) function, but it only allows to parse and validate SQL text, so it works a bit like a no-op `SQLPrepare`. It is not what I'm looking for.

Although, I'm hoping to find out the a generic plain ODBC solution and not specific to any DBMS, I mainly connect to SQL Server using the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server.

Comment: in which DBMS are you working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a wrapped method/function in ODBC API,
but you could try to call it directly from DB

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sql_handle)
```

Comment: Although I can't accept it as an answer, I appreciate it as an interesting alternative solution.  For the record/other readers, here is more complete example showing use of `sys.dm_exec_requests.sql_handle` column http://stackoverflow.com/a/31968654/151641